# How do I get another key binding for Alt+PrintScreen?

Tags: screenshot

now, that ubuntu 12.04 has the HUD popping up if you press the Alt key, Alt+PrintScreen only ends up taking screenshot of the launcher on the left. How do I get another key binding for Alt+PrintScreen?

Comment: Just curiosity. What does Alt + PrintScreen is meant to do?

Comment: @ Angel: Takes a screenshot of the current window. It works fine for me though. You have to hold down alt, then press PrScr. The HUD only appears if you tap alt, not when holding it down for an extended period of time.

Comment: If you want to change the shortcut anyway just head to System Settings --> Keyboard --> Shortcuts --> Screenshots

Comment: @Glutanimate Good to know. Shutter always solved that for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to put @Glutanimate comment as an answer:

Head to:

- System Settings

  - Keyboard

    - Shortcuts

      - Screenshots

Once there modify your shortcuts.